# wordpress add_query_arg how to add multiple queries to URL

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to use wordpress' add_query_arg function to add multiple queries to my url.

I can successfully add one query as follows:

```
esc_url(add_query_arg( 'booking-id', $the_query->post->ID, site_url( '/booking-form/' ) ))
```

However, I want my URL to read something like: www.yoursite.com/booking-form/?booking-id=xxx&user-id=xxx

How can I add a second query in to the existing function?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take a look at the official help on the function: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_query_arg/

```
// Parameters as array of key =&gt; value pairs
add_query_arg( array('key1' => 'value1', ...), $old_query_or_uri );
```

So for your example....

```
add_query_arg( array('booking-id' => $the_query->post->ID, 
  'user-id' => $userID),
  site_url( '/booking-form/' ) 
);
```

Where $userID is your user ID value (however you wish to get this)

Answer (score 0):

I referred [add_query_arg code reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_query_arg/)  and written this, I hope this will be helpful, please try and let me know.

```
$old_query_or_uri = '/booking-form/';
add_query_arg( array('booking-id' &#61; 'xxx', 'user-id' &#61; 'xxx' ), $old_query_or_uri );
```

Answer (score -1):

```
http://yoursite.com/?view=grid

<?php echo home_url('?view=list'); ?>

similer to 

<?php echo add_query_arg( 'view', 'list', home_url() ); ?>
```